# Using nested resources without the parent ID in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-resources, nested-routes

I have a class called `Imprintables` with nested resources `Styles`, `Brands`, `Colors`, and `Sizes`. I currently have this in my routes file:

```
resources :imprintables do
  resources :styles, :brands, :colors
  resources :sizes do
    collection do
      post 'update_size_order'
    end
  end
end
```

Which produces routes like this:

```
/imprintables/:imprintable_id/brands
/imprintables/:imprintable_id/colors
/imprintables/:imprintable_id/styles
/imprintables/:impritnable_id/sizes
```

I don't want to have all my nested resources tied to 1 specific imprintable. I want to have my routes look like:

```
/imprintables/brands
/imprintables/styles
/imprintables/colors
/imprintables/sizes
```

...etc.

Whats the best way to go about this?

Comment: Could you give a try to this [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) ? Also look at this [blogpost](http://jasoncodes.com/posts/rails-3-nested-resource-slugs).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
resources :imprintables do
  collection do
    resources :styles, :brands, :colors
  end
end
```